# Visual studio dataset objects layout not saved any more

Tags: visual-studio-2022

Why in visual studio 2022 version 17.0 data tables and adapters are no more saved in the same layout after the dataset file (*.xsd) is saved. Every time I save, close and reopen the (*.xsd) file I find all the objects either in a long single row up in the dataset or piled over each other in the left upper corner of the dataset.

I could not find a resolution for that problem.

Comment: I'm running into the same issue.

Comment: Are you using ReSharper?  I have the same issue.  Mine stopped saving the layout changes possibly with a VS update but also coincided with adding ReSharper.  I still haven't found the fix yet, though.